# MoPub install AdMob via CocoaPods

Tags: admob, cocoapods, mopub

I attempted to install AdMob support via cocoapods with the following podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'
pod 'mopub-ios-sdk/AdMob'
```

..and received the following error:

```
[!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/<username>/Documents/Developer/<app>/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.1.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework)
```

Any idea why that's happening?  I'm running El Capitan 10.11.4, CocoaPods 0.39.0, and XCode 7.3.

Comment: I get the same issue which goes away when I comment the use_frameworks! line out.  Unfortunately, I need to have the use_frameworks! in place because I use other pods which are written in swift, so I'm still looking for a solution myself, but if you only have those 2 pods, you could try to comment out the use_frameworks! line

Comment: Thanks @Teevus, I'll try that out if I go back to Mopub (trying Admob at the moment).

Comment: Also posted MoPub support's response to this question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer I received from MoPub support (on 3/29/2016):

> Thanks for reaching out!  Unfortunately, the AdMob cocoa pod
>   integration is currently broken.  Our team is aware of the problem and
>   is investigating it, but we do not have an ETA for when it will be
>   resolved.  I would recommend integrating AdMob by following these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Download the desired third party SDK and add the header files and
>      static libraries to your project. (For iAd you simply need to link
>      against the iAd framework, there is nothing to download).
> 2. Add the desired custom event to your project. You do this by cloning the
>      mopub-ios-sdkrepo and dragging the custom event .h and .m files from
>      the relevant SDK folder underAdNetworkSupport.
>
> We are so sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This is still broken a year later. Pretty unbelievable.

Comment: Still broken as of Sep 2, 2017.