# Could not find custom event class named MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent

Tags: xcode, swift, admob, mopub, twitter-fabric

I am having trouble integrating the AdMob SDK into MoPub (in Fabric).  I installed MoPub through the fabric installer. I am using iOS with Swift, XCode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014), base SDK iOS 9.3, project deployment target iOS 8.0.

I am able to display the MoPub test ads in my app but I get runtime errors when displaying the AdMob ads through MoPub.

I cannot find detailed instructions on how to integrate the AdMob SDK when using the Fabric MoPub installer.  Only instructions to add third party libraries when using the standalone MoPub SDK.  I would like to keep the Fabric MoPub framework.

After I got the MoPub test ads working, I followed these steps:

1. I added the GoogleAdMobCustomEvent.framework into the project, that came in the mopub-ios-custom-events.zip archive (found in https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios/mediation-fabric)
2. I added the GoogleMobileAds.framework (latest version from Google: v7.8.1) to the project.
3. In the MoPub dashboard, I created a new Order, with one Line Item and 2 ad units (banner and leaderboard) with the AdMob network.
4. When I run the project I get the following error:

   ```
   2016-05-28 12:03:57.662 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Banner view (*adunit id*) loading ad with MoPub server URL: *MoPub server URL*
   2016-05-28 12:04:00.909 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Could not find custom event class named MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent
   2016-05-28 12:04:00.910 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Banner ad view is fetching ad network type: admob_native
   2016-05-28 12:04:00.910 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Banner view (*adunit id*) loading ad with MoPub server URL: *MoPub server URL*
   2016-05-28 12:04:00.954 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Banner ad view is fetching ad network type: clear
   2016-05-28 12:04:00.954 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: No ads found for ad unit: *adunit id*
   2016-05-28 12:04:02.365 moPubTest[43756:2148130] MOPUB: Banner view (*adunit id*) failed. Error: Error Domain=com.mopub.iossdk Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.mopub.iossdk error 0.)"
   ```

It looks like I am missing a step. I am guessing the issue is when integrating the MoPub provided GoogleAdMobCustomEvent.framework (which is in Objective-C, and contains the MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent header) into my Swift project.

I've tried adding the frameworks to the project both by dragging and adding the files (selecting the copy files option). I also tried adding framework and header search paths, added a bridging header file, changed paths inside framework header files.

In all of the above the project compiles without errors but I still get the error at runtime: **Could not find custom event class named MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent**

Anyone ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I was able to get this to work by switching the Fabric and MoPub frameworks to be installed via CocoaPods (instead of using the Fabric app):

1. Installed Fabric and Mopub via CocoaPods
   https://fabric.io/kits/ios/mopub/install
2. Instead of adding the GoogleAdMobCustomEvent.framework, I added the following Objective-C files manually to the project:

   MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent.h
   MPGoogleAdMobBannerCustomEvent.m
   MPGoogleAdMobInterstitialCustomEvent.h
   MPGoogleAdMobInterstitialCustomEvent.m

   These 4 files can be found in the AdNetworkSupport folder of the ios mopub SDK git repo
3. Created a bridging header file with the following content:

   ```
   #import <mopub_ios_sdk/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>
   #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
   ```
4. I added the GoogleMobileAds.framework (latest version from Google: v7.8.1) to the project.
5. Added the path to the location of GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers in the Targets' "Search Paths" -> "Framework Search Path"

In theory you can also install MoPub's custom events via CocoaPads, but at the moment it is not possible because of a bug. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830967/6394927)

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I was in this situation right now.
I did the integration with Cocoapods and still I got this issue.

What you have to do (and is quite impossible to find in moPub documentation) is add to the Podfile the ad mediators you are working with. You can find it here https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/mediation/integrate/

In my case I had to add AdMob so I only had to add the following into the Podfile to make it work:

```
pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'
pod 'MoPub-AdMob-Adapters', '7.57.0.0'
```